# Mask string in ViewModel C#

Tags: c#, string, viewmodel, string-concatenation, data-masking

I have a view that pulls a list of everything in the database and it works great.  However there is one bit of information that I have to mask, and no matter what I try I can't seem to mask it.

I want to mask it with 5 * (no matter how long the string) and display the last 4 digits.

Any idea of the best way to accomplish this with what I have?

String example: "SD46346" && "ADFF3342422" && "56-AS4566S"

**Controller**

```
    vm.Accounts = accounts
        .Select(s => new AdminViewModel.Account
        {
            Id= (s._ID.Length > 40 ? Encryptor.Decrypt(s._ID) : s._ID),
        }).ToList();
    return View(vm);
```

**ViewModel**

```
public List<Account> Accounts { get; set;}

public class Account
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Things I've tried** : Server Error in '/xxxxx' Application. StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex –

```
public string DisplayID
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("*****{0}", Id.Substring(Id.Length - 4));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It wasn't my code, it was old data that was lost in the database that only had 2 characters.

Comment: Post sample of string.  Probably can use Regex.

Comment: Okay I will do that now

Comment: Substring with a negative index will just grab the last n characters - you don't need the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just after simple replacement for display, you could also add an extra property that you use for display purpose.

```
string ID {get;set;}

string DisplayID 
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("*****{0}", ID.substring(ID.Length - 4))
    }
}
```

Comment: Server Error in '/xxxxx' Application.

StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex

Comment: Always good to check string length is more than what you want. Looks like you've a shorter string length than 4.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little Overkill for your ask. But here is a quick extension method that does this.

it defaults to using x as the masking Char but can be changed with an optional char

**View Model**

```
string ID {get;set;}

string DisplayID 
{
    get
    {
        ID.MaskAllButLast(4,'*');
    }
}
```

**Extension Method**

```
   public static class Masking
{
    public static string MaskAllButLast(this string input, int charsToDisplay, char maskingChar = 'x')
    {
        int charsToMask = input.Length - charsToDisplay;
        return charsToMask > 0 ? $"{new string(maskingChar, charsToMask)}{input.Substring(charsToMask)}" : input;
    }
}
```

This should work error free and will not error for a short ID. It will also completely show a short id so there is that trade off.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the string (the double quotes and ampersand), but you should be able to modify the code as needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "SD46346\" && \"ADFF3342422\" && \"56-AS4566S";
            string pattern = @"\d{4}";  //exactly four digits in a row
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

            string output = match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I pull the output value to my view?

Comment: You will need an instance of the class Account.